# How can I store data from app engine datastore into csv file?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, datastore

I need to store the list of values querying from the datastore into a csv file

Here is my code that I am trying

```
//WriteCsvFileHandler is to
func WriteCsvFileHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
    kinDiagnosisList := []Diagnosis{}
    context := appengine.NewContext(r)

    //Getting Namespace
    namespace := ps.ByName("namespace")
    ctx, err := appengine.Namespace(context, namespace)
    if err != nil {
        log.Infof(ctx, "Namespace error from GetAllDiagnosisForEncounterHandler")
        RespondErr(w, r, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }
    file, err := os.Create("result.csv")
    checkError("Cannot create file", err)
    defer file.Close()

    writer := csv.NewWriter(file)
    defer writer.Flush()

    q := datastore.NewQuery("Diagnosis")
    data, err := q.GetAll(ctx, &kinDiagnosisList)
    if err != nil {
        log.Infof(ctx, "Keys generation error from GetAllDiagnosisForEncounterHandler")
        RespondErr(w, r, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }

    for _, value := range  {
        err := writer.Write(value)
        checkError("Cannot write to file", err)
    }
}

func checkError(message string, err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(message, err)
    }
}
```

How can I store the list of diagnosis coming from datastore into csv file?

Answer (score 0):

Is there an error you are experiencing?

How large is the set of entities you need to be able to output?

The robust answer is to use Google Dataflow, but you'd have to write that job in java or python.

Otherwise, if you need a solution that is less involved, you'd have to build the file in memory before your handler serves it. If the request timeout is your issue, you could call that handler via Google TaskQueue to get the timeout bumped up to 10 minutes and write the file to Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: err := writer.Write(value) value wont take list.is there any way to backup the data

Comment: I use python, so I'm not entirely sure, but I think the problem originates from here `file, err := os.Create("result.csv")` App engine Standard doesnt let you just write to arbitrary files, try to build the csv file in memory and then write it to Google Cloud Storage